# Can't use retrieved data from one query into another one?

Tags: sql, asp.net

I need to use a variable (edifcodigo) which assigned value is retrieved from one query to insert it in a table by using other query but there is a error that says this variable is not available in actual context. I'm kind of new in aspnet, could anybody know how to figure this out?

This is the code I have:

```
//Connect to db
string connetionString = @"myconexionstring";
string sql = "SELECT TOP 1 id_proyecto AS codigo FROM DNN_SCO_PROY_CO_PROYECTO_TBL WHERE nombre_proyecto= '"+ uedif +"'";

//find building code by querying the database
try
{
    using (SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection(connetionString))
    {
        conexion.Open();
        using (SqlCommand query = new SqlCommand(sql, conexion))
        {
            SqlDataReader result = query.ExecuteReader();
            while (result.Read())
            {
                string edifcodigo = result["codigo"].ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Response.Write(ex.Message);
}

//Save referer friend
try
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connetionString))
    {
    conn.Open();
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("DNN_SVI_SCO_DATOS_RECOMIENDA_AMIGO_SP", conn))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@DRA_PROYECTO_CLIENTE", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = edifcodigo; ;
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Response.Write(ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: unrelated to question, but wouldn't it be easier to just write 1 single SQL statement that calls the procedure with  the value from that table? That's half the code volume that you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are declaring the string variable inside your while loop, it loses scope once you exit the while loop, move it's declaration above with:

```
string connetionString = @"myconexionstring";
string sql = "SELECT TOP 1 id_proyecto AS codigo FROM DNN_SCO_PROY_CO_PROYECTO_TBL WHERE nombre_proyecto= '"+ uedif +"'";
string edifcodigo = "";
```

Comment: but that would my variable adquire a value=""... And the idea is to usethe value I'm getting from the first query and insert it into a table by using the second query

Comment: @DolarpamiPami You would still set its value in the while loop, just not declare it there. So instead of this in your while loop: string edifcodigo = result["codigo"].ToString(); it would be edifcodigo = result["codigo"].ToString();

Comment: you guys are awesome, Thanks for the helping me

Answer (score 1):

That's because you declared the variable inside a different code block. Every time you open a curly bracket, you open a new code block. Every time you close the curly bracket, you close the current code block. Each code block have it's own scope - it can access variables declared in the surrounding code block, but not variables declared in "sibling" code blocks.

Also, please read about parameterized queries and how they protect you from SQL injection, and change your queries accordingly.

Also, you don't need to close the connection between the two commands, and you can reuse a single command instance in this case. Here is an improved version of your code:

```
//Connect to db
var connetionString = @"myconexionstring";
var sql = "SELECT TOP 1 id_proyecto AS codigo FROM DNN_SCO_PROY_CO_PROYECTO_TBL WHERE nombre_proyecto = @nombre_proyecto"; 

//find building code by querying the database
try
{
    using (var conexion = new SqlConnection(connetionString))
    {
        conexion.Open();
        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conexion))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@nombre_proyecto", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = uedif;
            var edifcodigo = cmd.ExecuteScalar();

            //Save referer friend
            cmd.Parameters.Clear();
            cmd.CommandText = "DNN_SVI_SCO_DATOS_RECOMIENDA_AMIGO_SP";
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@DRA_PROYECTO_CLIENTE", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = edifcodigo; ;
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Response.Write(ex.Message);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use a variable that declared in another scope. edifcodigo should be declared in the parent scope of both try blocks.

```
//Connect to db
string connetionString = @"myconexionstring";
string sql = "SELECT TOP 1 id_proyecto AS codigo FROM DNN_SCO_PROY_CO_PROYECTO_TBL WHERE nombre_proyecto= '"+ uedif +"'";

string edifcodigo="";    // YOU SHOULD DECLARE edifcodigo HERE
```

and than rest of code will come

```
//find building code by querying the database
try
{
    using (SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection(connetionString))
    {
        conexion.Open();
        using (SqlCommand query = new SqlCommand(sql, conexion))
        {
            SqlDataReader result = query.ExecuteReader();
            while (result.Read())
            {
                edifcodigo = result["codigo"].ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Response.Write(ex.Message);
}

//Save referrer friend
try
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connetionString))
    {
        conn.Open();

        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("DNN_SVI_SCO_DATOS_RECOMIENDA_AMIGO_SP", conn))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@DRA_PROYECTO_CLIENTE", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = edifcodigo; ;
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Response.Write(ex.Message);
}
```